# GLib macro documentation

Tags: c, glib

From [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html#g-array-append-val):

> **g_array_append_val()**
>
> ```
> #define             g_array_append_val(a,v)
> ```
>
> Adds the value on to the end of the array. The array will grow in size automatically if necessary.
>
> `g_array_append_val()` is a macro which uses a reference to the value parameter `v` . This means that you cannot use it with literal values such as "27". You must use variables.
>
> Parameters
>
> `a`     a GArray
>
> `v` the value to append to the GArray

Is it possible that all the macro definitions like this one are not quite correct? Isn't `a` a *pointer* to a GArray?

Comment: Yes `a` is a pointer to `GArray`. Which is called as a `GArray` here.

Comment: @MohitJain: ... then the above *documentation* is inaccurate, to not say wrong, as it then should read "*`a` a `GArray *`*".

Comment: "*reference*" is also inaccurate, as there are no "references" in C.

Comment: @alk Agreed completely. But then it might be the terminology of their documentation (that I am not completely aware of).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the terminology of the document is to call pointer to `GArray` as a `GArray`. (Which is not accurate IMO).

For example look at the next item:

> ## g_array_append_vals ()
>
> ```
> GArray *
> g_array_append_vals (GArray *array,
>                      gconstpointer data,
>                      guint len);
> ```
>
> Adds len elements onto the end of the array.
>
> **Parameters**
> array a GArray
> ...
> **Returns**
>  the GArray

Here array is clearly a pointer to `GArray`.

---

From [LPs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689479/glib-macro-documentation/36689672#comment60967941_36689672) the possible reason for this is possibly because objects of GArray can not be created. (It is an opaque pointer if I remember correctly) and the new array that you get by calling `g_array_new()` has type `GArray *`.

Comment: I guess it depends form the fact that you cannot simply define a `GArray`, you must create it with `g_array_new()`. Then all functions, I guess, need a `GArray` pointer.

Comment: From looking at the source it seems that in `g_array_new()` a pointer to a struct `GRealArray` is cast with `(GArray *)` before it is returned. So it makes the other members of `GRealArray` inaccessible.